# Cracks between ceiling and walls

Tags: drywall

I live on the coast of North Carolina. The house was build in the 1986. I had mold under the house and places inside. I had a crew to get rid the mold in the house and replace the insulation and plastic under the house. The crawl space was sealed and a dehumidifier was installed under the house. I now have cracks between the ceiling and the walls. The laminate flooring seems to be separating. What might be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably caused by the change in humidity.  Now that the crawl space is dry everything is drying out, once things are good and dry for several months then would be the time to repair the drywall cracks.the laminate flooring may be more of a problem now that it is drying out and shrinking hopefully it won't get worse and I would expect it to settle down within a month or two.